# Filtering JSON with underscore

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

Given a data structure like so:

```
"items":
         {
         "Groups":[
            {
               "title":"group 1",
               "SubGroups":[
                  {
                     "title":"sub1",
                     "id" : "1",
                     "items":[
                        {
                           "title":"Ajax request 1",
                        },
                        {
                           "title":"Ajax request 2",
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                    {
                     "title":"sub2",
                     "id" : "2",
                     "items":[
                        {
                           "title":"Ajax request 3",
                        },
                        {
                           "title":"Ajax request 4",
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
```

How can I pull out all the items for a sub group based on the id? Ive treid using find like so:

```
var res1 = _.where(listing.items,{id:"2"});
```

but get an empty array returned

Thanks

Comment: Have you parsed your `JSON` first? You can't use underscore directly on `JSON`,  but on javascript objects

Comment: Hi, yes its already a javascript object

Comment: You need a much deeper search than that

Comment: @charlietf - cheers. Would it be possible to provide an answer I can accept?

Comment: You need to get into the Groups and Subgroups arrays. You are only scratching the surface

Answer (score 2):

Try targeting the subgroups array and then search for the id you want in there. That should then return the properties for that subgroup.

```
var obj = {
    "Groups": [{
        "title": "group 1",
        "SubGroups": [{
            "title": "sub1",
            "id": "1",
            "items": [{
                "title": "Ajax request 1",
            }, {
                "title": "Ajax request 2",
            }]
        }, {
            "title": "sub2",
            "id": "2",
            "items": [{
                "title": "Ajax request 3",
            }, {
                "title": "Ajax request 4",
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

then find values like this

```
_.where(obj.Groups[0].SubGroups, {
   'id': '2'
});
```

Just tested and this seems to work

Comment: That's great thanks, in reality there will be multiple top level groups I will need to search through, how do I search all groups rather than the first one?

Comment: you could loop over each of the groups using _.each and search for the values inside there - see https://jsfiddle.net/Lcxsqdbm/